# Подключение к базе данных Bitrix24

Tags: php, база-данных, битрикс

Здравствуйте уважаемые, подскажите пожалуйста как бы мне подключиться к БД bitrix24 и вытянуть к себе на сайт список моих контактов?

Answer (score 1):

Структура бд которую использует битрикс не так проста, и забрать какие то данные напрямую через таблицу, вероятнее всего что ты потеряешь часть каких то данных. Если есть возможность, лучше вытяни данные в самом битриксе и сформируй какой нибудь csv файл, и затем перенеси уже все необходимые данные к себе на сайт(на свою платформу). Уточни вопрос, что именно ты хочешь получить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Мне нужно каждый день (по крону) собирать отчет о сделках и отправлять ее на почту. Что не выкачивать каждый день XML, а систематизировать этот процесс

Comment: В чем проблемы на текущий момент? Я предполагаю что есть некоторый инфоблок с которого нужно получить определенные данные, их сформировать и отправить на почту

Comment: Проблема в том что я пока не понимаю как получить данные с определенного инфоблока.

Comment: Вот уже более конкретный вопрос) Для получения записей с определенного инфоблока можно воспользоваться CIBlockElement::GetList (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php) .

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать для своей задачи использовать коннектор, он в вашу БД все данные из Битркис24 - https://www.bitrix24.ru/apps/?app=remark.b24storage

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)